# dispatchEvent not preforming event, but returns true

Tags: javascript, dom-events, event-dispatching

On MDC's site they have a [cool demo of dispatchEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/domref/dispatchEvent.html) that works fine in my Chrome 15.

I'm trying to take an event object and pass it into `dispatchEvent`, and have set up [a simple case here](http://jsfiddle.net/u27xb/) where you record events as an array then will replay them.

In essence, I set up a window listener for click, and then perform `window.dispatchEvent(recordedEvent)`.

I'm unable to determine why my event object from the event listener will not preform the same way as the event from `initMouseEvent` in the MDC example.

I'm not really worried with making it work, I want to know **why** this doesn't work, when after [reading the funny manual](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-EventTarget-dispatchEvent) it seems to imply it should.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like it works just fine to me; [here](http://jsfiddle.net/u27xb/2/) is an update.

*edit* — wait - is your concern about the fact that it's returning `true` as if "preventDefault()" was called?  If so then I understand your confusion now.

*edit finally* OK I think I see the issue. When you're dispatching the event, you always dispatch from `window`.  If instead you [keep track of the elements](http://jsfiddle.net/u27xb/3/) involved, then it works.

Here's the good code that works (for me in Firefox 7):

```
//Vars for the elements we're working with
var replay = document.getElementById("replay");
var replaying = false;

//Handler to record events into a data array.
var handler = function (e) {
    if (replaying) {
        console.log("replay " + e.type);
    }
    else if (e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'input') {
        return;
            }
    else {
        handler.data.push({elem: e.target, event: e});
        console.log(handler.data);
    }
};
handler.data = [];

//Listen for the click on the replay button   
replay.addEventListener("click", function(){
    //Remove listeners so we don't create some crazy
    //infinite paradox with turtles all the way down
    // window.removeEventListener("click", handler);
    replaying = true;

    //Clear the textbox out
    var status = [], obj;
    //Dispatch a bunch of stored up events
    for (var i=0; i<handler.data.length;i++){
        obj = handler.data[i];
        status.push(obj.elem.dispatchEvent(obj.event));
    }
    console.log(status);
    replaying = false;
});

//Listen for some specific events
//window.addEventListener("keyup", handler);
window.addEventListener("click", handler);
```

Also note that it's good to avoid saving the "click" events on the "Replay" button itself.

Comment: I'm glad I'm not the only one taken back by the way it behaves. Which browser are you using? I can't seem to get click events to check/uncheck the boxes as per the MDN example.

Comment: Note that the MDN example ([here](https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/domref/dispatchEvent.html)) interprets the status value in the opposite way!  In other words, it thinks that `true` means that none of the handlers called "preventDefault()".

Comment: Oh also when you dispatch the event you probably should dispatch the event from the target element - I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: Awesome answer man, you've got me going on the right track. It works in FF, now I've got to figure out why it's inconsistent between browsers that supposedly support this feature.